# get result of nested click function

Tags: javascript

Is it possible something like this:

```
$('#btna').click(function(){
    console.log(abc());
})

function abc() {
    $('#btnb').click(function(){
        var result = false;
    });
    $('#btnc').click(function(){
        var result = true;
    });
    return result;
}
```

So clicking on `btna` I need to **wait** while `btnb` or `btnc` is clicked and write that result in console.

Any help?

Comment: Do you want to wait for both b and c to be clicked, or just one or the other? Based on your question, it sounds like the latter, but based on the answer you accepted, it sounds like the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other Way to do, its using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), this will run in especific order waiting for previous click, except the first button (**`$btna`**)

```js
const $btna = document.getElementById('btna');
const $btnb = document.getElementById('btnb');
const $btnc = document.getElementById('btnc');


function executeListener(btn ){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    btn.addEventListener("click" , function(){
      let jsonReturn = {
        action : "click" ,
        button : btn
      }
      resolve(jsonReturn)
    });
  })
}
executeListener($btna)
.then(function(btnaSuccess) {
  console.log("click btna");
  return executeListener($btnb)
}).then(function(btnbSuccess){
  console.log("click btnb");
  return executeListener($btnc);
}).then(function(btncSuccess){
  console.log("click btnc")
  console.log("Chispas");
})
```

```html
<button id="btna">btna</button>
<button id="btnb">btnb</button>
<button id="btnc">btnc</button>
```

Also, you could use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
const $btna = document.getElementById('btna');
const $btnb = document.getElementById('btnb');
const $btnc = document.getElementById('btnc');


function executeListener(btn ){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    btn.addEventListener("click" , function(){
      let jsonReturn = {
        action : "click" ,
        button : btn
      }
      resolve(jsonReturn)
    });
  })
}
Promise.all([
executeListener($btna), 
executeListener($btnb),
executeListener($btnc)])
.then(values => { 
  console.log("resolve all clicks");  
  console.log("Chispas")
  
  

});
```

```html
<button id="btna">btna</button>
<button id="btnb">btnb</button>
<button id="btnc">btnc</button>
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. I just want to know is this possible using jquery, in order to code less. Anyway - accepted.

Comment: You didn't write that , but I'm happy for you, anyway , I prefer native JavaScript because if I have to change the library I will not have problems switching to another library;

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to wait for *all* the buttons to be clicked (which seems to be the case given the answer you accepted), and assuming you are using ECMA 2017, you can use the more modern `async`/`await` pattern.

```js
const btna = $("#btna");
const btnb = $("#btnb");
const btnc = $("#btnc");

async function handler(btn) {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
     btn.on("click", () => {
        resolve(`clicked ${btn.attr("id")}`);
     });
   });
}

(async () => { 
  let values = await Promise.all([handler(btna), handler(btnb), handler(btnc)]);
  console.log(values); 
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btna">btna</button>
<button id="btnb">btnb</button>
<button id="btnc">btnc</button>
```

Based on your question though, it sounds like you don't want to wait until *all* buttons are clicked. You just want to log different values when `btnb` is clicked after `btna` vs `btnc` is clicked after `btna`. In that case, you don't need promises at all and can just do this:

```js
const btna = $("#btna");
const btnb = $("#btnb");
const btnc = $("#btnc");

btna.click(() => {
    btnb.on("click", clickHandler);
    btnc.on("click", clickHandler);
});

function clickHandler() {
  console.log(this.id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btna">btna</button>
<button id="btnb">btnb</button>
<button id="btnc">btnc</button>
```

Comment: more info [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)